# How we should store access_tokens in reactJS based web application?

Tags: reactjs, jwt, local-storage

I have a React + Typescript webapp which is storing multiple access_tokens in local storage of the browser to be accessible to all modules. These tokens are generated from back-end and help to authenticate every API call from the application. Since it is not advisable to store such information I need to find a way so that every module can still utilise this common access_token and no browser storage is used to store it.

Help me pointing to the direction where I should look for solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

NOTE : I have edited the original question to my specifics. Since there are many solutions available for one JWT post login. But in my scenario I have to deal with multiple JWTs.

Can I get some help on how we should store multiple JWTs without using any browser storage ?

Comment: I send mine down as a secure cookie which gets sent back up with every request... so, basically the browser does it....

Comment: Do you want auto login? If so, use local storage. If not, session storage. You can also use cookies. But, now that we have options for local storage and session storage, I tend to use those. Also, its true there's a certain degree of risk involved in storing JWTs in cookie or storage, but everybody does that. Even the big boys. There are no other options. So, don't worry store it in local storage and make sure you implement refresh tokens along with access token.

Comment: If the security side still troubles you that you are using local storage, then you can always encrypt the tokens on the server and then send it to the browser. But, there's a performance penalty for doing this because you will have to decrypt the token on each request and its serves little to no purpose in actuality. I think encrypting tokens is an overkill. But, its always an option.